# Can this be done by physics in Blender?

Tags: modeling, physics, soft-body

I saw this and I'm trying to figure it out how can I make this by physics features. I tested some different ways, but since I'm not advanced in this feature of the blender, I want to ask you if it's possible or not and if yes, could you kindly give me some advice?

Here is the image:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: of course not, you cant do that with physics, to do that you have to model it

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid I’m guessing the question is about the bulging cushion sections being generated by physics, similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/87424/29586

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definetiley possible.

I can recommend to check out Curtis Holt's Video on Cloth Simulation in Blender 2.8 The effect you want to have is definetly doable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAswwNpfe0U&t=0s&list=LL_vK2be21gQ3oN11drA3XBA&index=8

You would have to start by modelling your base structure and the plastic in the state of "not stretched out".